# How to compare each matrix to mean and return value in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, mean

for example lets consider

```
a = fix(8 * randn(10,5));
```

and `mean(a)` would give me mean of each column.

So, what I was planning to do was comparing the mean of first column to each of its content till the column and and proceed to the next column with its mean and comparing with each of its content.

I was able to get this code here (I know there are multiple for loops but thats the best I could come up with, any alternate answer would be greatly accepted)

```
if(ndims(a)==2)
    b = mean(a);
   for c = 1:size(a,2)
       for d = 1:size(a)
           for e = 1:size(b,2)
                if(a(d,c)>b(1,c))
                    disp(1);
                else
                    disp(false);
                end
           end
       end
   end

else
    disp('Input should be a 2D matrix');
end
```

I don't know if this is the right answer? Could any one tell me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to know **whether each entry is greater than its column-mean**.

This is done efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = bsxfun(@gt, a, mean(a,1));
```

---

Example:

```
a =
     3     1     3     2
     5     2     3     1
     1     3     5     2
```

The column-means, given by `mean(a,1)`,  are

```
ans =
   3.000000000000000   2.000000000000000   3.666666666666667   1.666666666666667
```

Then

```
>> result = bsxfun(@gt, a, mean(a,1))
result =
     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: this is perfect but instead of 0 will i be able to get -1?

Comment: That's easy: `result = 2*bsxfun(@gt, a, mean(a,1))-1;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do what I think you are (print one if the average value of a column is  greater than the value in that column, zero otherwise) you can eliminate a lot of loops doing the following (using your same a and b):

```
    for ii=1:length(b)
       c(:,ii) = b(ii) > a(:,ii);
    end
```

c will be your array of ones and zeros.

Comment: this is perfect but instead of 0 will i be able to get -1?

Comment: Whenever assigning a comparison to an array, you'll just get 0 or 1 (false or true for the result).  If you wanted to get -1 in there you can do something similar to what @Luis Mendo suggested:  c = 2*c - 1; once you're out of the for loop.